# how make this sql query faster

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

i have a query on mysql that runs terribly slow eventually. the query is as below.

```
select v.product_id, v.product_name, c.price,c.customer_id, 
            n.customer_name, date_start, date_end 
            from vol_product v 
            left outer join cus_pro_price c on v.product_id=c.product_id 
            left outer join ntt_customer n on n.customer_id=c.customer_id 
            where v.status!='110' and  date_end >='2022-04-01' 
            and date_end between '2022-04-01' and '2022-10-31'
```

this query is running inside an application that has been running over 10 years. originally there is no performance issue when the tables were small.

MySQL 3.23

SQL query: describe vol_product;

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
product_name    varchar(50) NO          
product_unit_id varchar(4)  NO          
status  int(11) NO      0   
product_id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
sort_order  int(11) NO      0   
quo_price   double(16,4)    NO      0.0000
```

SQL query: describe ntt_customer;

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra

customer_id int(11) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
customer_name   varchar(50) NO          
country_id  char(2) NO      h   
address varchar(80) YES     NULL    
tel varchar(20) NO          
fax varchar(20) YES     NULL    
credit_limit    double(16,4) unsigned   YES     NULL    
credit_balance  double(16,4) unsigned   YES     NULL    
day_allowance   int(11) unsigned    NO      30  
status_id   int(11) NO      0   
official_name   varchar(50) NO          
customer_no varchar(20) NO          
line_no int(11) NO      80
```

SQL query: describe cus_pro_price;

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra

id  int(10) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
customer_id int(11) NO  MUL 0   
product_id  int(11) NO      0   
price   double(16,2)    NO      0.00    
date_start  date    NO      0000-00-00  
date_end    date    YES     0000-00-00  
date_add    datetime    YES     0000-00-00 00:00:00 

autostatus  enum('0','1')   NO      0
```

There are no indexes defined for the table.

but now the table size:

```
vol_product ~400
ntt_customer ~400
cus_pro_price ~480,000
```

cus_pro_price is time related data so there is a date_end and date_created fields.

actually in the 480,000 rows of the cus_pro_price, only about 16000 would be of interested of this query and i can actually narrow down the rows by date_end between (before_date and limit_date).

i think the above query now is filtered by date after join, do you think if i can filter date before join, would it be much faster? how?

thanks.

Comment: Please include your table schema and existing indexes. Why do you have a redundant clause on `date_end`?

Comment: And a valid query!

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @stu, what do you mean redundant clause? the part "and  date_end >='$before_date' 
            and date_end between '$before_date' and '$limit_date'", if yes, that may be a mistake.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have amended the query, is that now the valid query you said?

Comment: If X between 5 and 10 is true then X  >= 5 is also true

Comment: Instead of `describe <tablename>` use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`.  That will return you the create statements including all indexes.

Comment: "that may be a mistake" - then fix it first.

Comment: `date_end` is a column from `cus_pro_price`, so `left outer join cus_pro_price c` is INNER JOIN.

Comment: @DennisChan Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> There are no indexes defined for the table.

There's the *problem*.  To fix that, I suggest:

```
c:  INDEX(date_end, product_id,  price, customer_id, date_start)
```

The query, as currently written, is testing `c.date_end >='2022-04-01'` twice.  (This is not a performance issue.)

To discuss further, please answer these:

- How big are the tables now?
- Are the tables `ENGINE=InnoDB` (they should be).
- What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size?
- How much RAM?

Comment: the 3 tables involved only cus_pro_price is big with 490K records. other tables with hundreds of lines only. My mysql server is only 3.23, I think it should be MyISAM. no InnoDB so no buffer_pool_size set. and by cat /proc/meminfo, my system has cat /proc/meminfo
        total:    used:    free: 
Mem:  1054953472 1038528512 16424960 
Swap: 2146787328 23691264 2123096064

Comment: Yikes!  4.0 came in more than 2 decades ago; that's when InnoDB was added.  Hold on a minute while I dig through my pile of punched cards to find MyISAM.

Comment: What is the setting of `key_buffer_size`?

Comment: Wait...  You said "MySQL 5.5.62' in the Question, but now you are saying "3.23"???

Comment: How many rows in the result?  With only 1GB of RAM, I suspect it cannot keep enough of the data cached to be fast.  The index I suggested should help, maybe enough.  Using smaller numeric data types (where practical) will help some.